# not able to send mail with mercury 32 on XAMPP win 7

Tags: php, email

i am trying to send mail with mercury 32 and xampp on windows 7 machine.
i have configured the mercury according to this manual:
http://system66.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html

and have managed sending a mail to my localhost user with outlock but my php script won't work.

here is the php.ini settings i use:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in  the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

and my script:

```
            $to = 'root@localhost.com';
        $subject = 'try1';
        $body =  'try1';
        $headers = "From: postmaster@localhost";

        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers )){
        echo 'email was sent';
        }
```

it writes the email was send but i dont get it in the localhost user on outlock. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just very quickly your root@localhost.com should just be root@localhost unless you set an alias, this video is the best I've found for explaining the full process: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QnfF64rA78